# Who is telling where cur,new and tmp are created using Postfixadmin with Maildir

Tags: postfix, dovecot, maildir

I was trying to realized which configuration is telling where cur,tmp and new are created. Of course I've beein using virtual user and I receive and send mails into `virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir/new` and `virtualuser/Maildir/cur` (I think `virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir/tmp` is very temporarilly and never get and email) but when I create a new Mailbox using Postfixadmin it created like that

```
virtualuser/domain/user/tmp
virtualuser/domain/user/new
virtualuser/domain/user/cur
```

then I just need to move this tree folders inside

```
 virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir (this is how i would I would like to be created) so I would have:

 virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir/cur
 virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir/tmp
 virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir/new
```

So in which configuration file have this setting? Is Postfix, Dovecot or Postfixadmin?

In addition I have this conf:

```
# Postfix:
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
local_transport = dovecot
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
relay_domains = $mydestination
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/virtualuser
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = virtual

 Dovecot:
 mail_home = 
 mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

And /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf has:

```
 ...
 table = mailbox
 select_field = maildir
 where_field = username
```

and get from database a folder string like "virtualuser/domain/user"

Comment: Dunno... it depends on your configuration... Please post the output of `postconf -n`

Comment: could you please read again, I think now is little bit clear. it create like virtualuser/domain/user/new and i would like to be like :  virtualuser/domain/user/Maildir/new  . Now I think , It whould be Postfixadmin configuration, am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [postfixadmin FAQ](https://github.com/svn2github/PostfixAdmin/blob/65877c19ba5ff2ddadc882ef92323e22e26e536d/DOCUMENTS/FAQ.txt)

> 1) Why isn't PostfixAdmin creating my mailbox?
>
> > PostfixAdmin is only a web interface for storing configuration settings. 
> >     It does not (by default!) have the ability to create mail folders on disk. 
> >     In a normal setup, sending the 'Welcome' email accomplishes this task - 
> >     as Courier/Cyrus/etc do it (and have permission to do so)

So, we can conclude that postfix or dovecot who rule the location of your maildir...

---

Based from output of `postconf -n` above, apparently you use postfix [virtual agent](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html) to perform incoming email delivery to Maildir. So we need to learn how `virtual` agent pick destination mailbox of incoming email. Taken from man 8 virtual

> The mailbox location is controlled by the virtual_mailbox_base and virtual_mailbox_maps  configuration  parameters  (see  below).   The  virtual_mailbox_maps   table  is  indexed  by  the  recipient  address  as described under TABLE SEARCH ORDER below.
>
> The mailbox pathname is constructed as follows:
>
> ```
>     $virtual_mailbox_base/$virtual_mailbox_maps(recipient)
> ```
>
> where recipient is the full recipient address.

So, in your case (`/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf`), `$virtual_mailbox_maps` will selected with this query

```
SELECT maildir FROM mailbox WHERE username = $recipient;
```

Together with `$virtual_mailbox_base`, they construct the absolute path of mailbox.

Now, the question is where maildir field generated? Postfixadmin use 3 parameters to generated the `maildir` field,

- $CONF['domain_path']
- $CONF['domain_in_mailbox']
- $CONF['maildir_name_hook']

You can search the explanation of those parameters in `config.inc.php` of postfixadmin.

---

So, if you need append **/Maildir** in `virtual_mailbox_maps`, then you can

1. Alter `select_field` of `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf`.
2. Write your `maildir_name_hook` function in postfixadmin.

*If you plan to use option 1, you also needs to change the parameter of dovecot, especially in `userdb` parameter. Look for `home` field or `mail_location` field.*

Comment: Weird , my virtual_mailbox_maps.cf look like this:                               table = mailbox
select_field = maildir
where_field = username                                                                                  and get from database a folder like "virtualuser/domain/user" because at some point something created like that in the db maildir field, and as far as I know should  be the one who inserted in the table ,  say postfixadmin getting the parameters from postfix , I'm i right? but , you see my postfix configuration? everything look ok to me. Do I miss something?

Comment: I don't familiar with postfixadmin. Please edit the question and post the content of `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf`, `config.inc.php` from postfixadmin and version of postfixadmin

Comment: @MikZuit, see updated answer

Comment: You're right @masegaloeh , and you beat me for little hours I would resolve this for myself (think so) . Is postfixadmin with the $CONF['maildir_name_hook'] , you neew to create a function as config.inc.php to set the Maildir path as you want. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

if you get from database a folder string like "virtualuser/domain/user" you should not have these 3 folders.

But if you get from database a folder string like "virtualuser/domain/user/" you should not have these 3 folders.